# Hyperledger fabric gateway is not able to get network

Tags: networking, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am developing a Fabric application, and I am facing the issue where gateway is not able to get the network

366 | await gateway.connect(ccp, gatewayOpts);

367 | const network = await gateway.getNetwork(channelName);
| ^
368 | const contract = network.getContract(chaincodeName);
In Line number 367 I am facing an error

Following is the error :-

2021-07-24T13:39:03.866Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2021-07-24T13:39:03.867Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0.org1.example.com url:grpcs://localhost:7051 timeout:3000
2021-07-24T13:39:03.893Z - info: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - Unable to connect to the endorser peer0.org1.example.com due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
at checkState (/home/user/Documents/Learnings/aries-learning/aries-javascript/aries-framework-javascript/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:169:18)
at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/user/Documents/Learnings/aries-learning/aries-javascript/aries-framework-javascript/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/channel.ts:579:9)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
connectFailed: true
}
2021-07-24T13:39:07.452Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Discoverer- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2021-07-24T13:39:07.452Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0.org1.example.com url:grpcs://localhost:7051 timeout:3000
2021-07-24T13:39:07.453Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: ServiceEndpoint grpcs://localhost:7051 reset connection failed :: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Discoverer- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2021-07-24T13:39:07.453Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: send[mychannel] - no discovery results

Can anyone help me in resolving this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That can be many things, but is quite often a TLS issue. Check the peer logs. You may see a Bad TLS message, etc. Or notice that it does not have an attempt to contact it, so it might be dns, or more general connectivity issues.

Comment: Hi @jworthington , Yes, there are no logs in the peer , So we can say that it is not contacting the peer , but how should I resolve this?

Comment: I don't know your network definition, but I guess you are using the standard local test_network. So there really shouldn't be any communication issues as they are all likely local docker images and all that works out of the box for everything local. But you can ping the servers, try telnet, etc. If the network is external to the JDK machine, then ip address instead of 'localhost' or similar may be the issue. If external, firewalls and such can interfere. telnet servername port should get you a telnet console if all tcp/ip communication is available. I'd turn debug on for the peer, also.